# Find the following limit problem

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find the following limit 
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \left({1-\sin x } {\cos x}\right)^{{ \csc 2x} }$$
How to prove the above limit equals $e^{-{1\over2}}$?

Comment: One method: Write your limit as an e-power so that the exponent can be put at a multiplication rather than a power.

Comment: As $x \to 0$,
$\left[1 - \sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)\right]^{\csc\left(2x\right)} \sim
\left(1 - x\right)^{1/\left(2x\right)} =
\,\sqrt{\,\left(1 + {\color{#f00}{-1} \over 1/x}\right)^{1/x}\,}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mathrm{as}\ x\ \to\ 0}{\to}\,\,\,
\,\sqrt{\,\mathrm{e}^{-1}\,}\, = \mathrm{e}^{-1/2}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$(1-\sin(x)\cos(x))^{\csc(2x)}=\left(1-\frac1{2\csc(2x)}\right)^{\csc(2x)}$$

Let $t=2\csc(2x)$.  Then, we have

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}(1-\sin(x)\cos(x))^{\csc(2x)}=\lim_{t\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{1}{t}\right)^{\frac t2}$$

Comment: @felixmarin Thank you my friend!

Answer (score 4):

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \left(1-\sin x \cos x\right)^{\csc 2x}=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(1-\sin x \cos x\right)^{\frac{1}{\sin 2x}}=$$
$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \left(1-\sin x \cos x\right)^{\frac{1}{\sin x\cos x}\frac{1}{2}}=e^{-1\cdot\frac{1}{2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$(1-\sin x \cos x)^{\csc 2x}=(1-\sin x \cos x)^{\frac{1}{\sin 2x}}=\left[(1-\sin x \cos x)^{\frac{1}{\sin x \cos }}\right]^{\sin x \cos x \cdot \frac{1}{\sin 2x}}=\left[(1-\sin x \cos x)^{\frac{1}{\sin x \cos }}\right]^{\sin x \cos x \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sin x \cos x}}=\left[(1-\sin x \cos x)^{\frac{1}{\sin x \cos }}\right]^{\frac{1}{2 }}$

Answer (score 2):

The way the formula appears,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1-\sin(x)\cos(x)\right)^{\csc(2x)}
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1-\frac12\sin(2x)\right)^{\csc(2x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1-\frac1{2\csc(2x)}\right)^{\csc(2x)}\\[4pt]
&=e^{-1/2}
\end{align}
$$
However, the LaTeX seems to indicate that the problem may have meant to ask
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{x\to 0}\left((1-\sin(x))\cos(x)\right)^{\csc(2x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1-\sin(x)\right)^{\csc(2x)}\cos(x)^{\csc(2x)}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1-\sin(x)\right)^{\csc(2x)}\left(1-\sin^2(x)\right)^{\csc(2x)/2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1-\sin(x)\right)^{3\csc(2x)/2}\left(1+\sin(x)\right)^{\csc(2x)/2}\\
&=\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1-\frac1{\csc(x)}\right)^{3\csc(x)\sec(x)/4}\lim_{x\to 0}\left(1+\frac1{\csc(x)}\right)^{\csc(x)\sec(x)/4}\\[4pt]
&=e^{-3/4}e^{1/4}\\[9pt]
&=e^{-1/2}
\end{align}
$$
Both interpretations give the desired answer since as $x\to0$, $\csc(x)\to\infty$.